# Why aren't the properties of my object logged to the console?

Tags: javascript, logging, properties, console

Below, I have constructed an object called person and I want to log its first and last name(combined with some strings) to the console, but it does not work. I would be glad if somebody could help me out. Thank you in advance.

```
function person(last, first, birth, marriage) {
this.lastName = last;
this.firstName = first;
this.birthDate = birth;
this.married = marriage;
}

var lovely = new person("Doughnut", "Glazed", "7-8-1990", true);

var callPerson = function(){
console.log("Hey " + person.firstName + " " + person.lastName);
}

callPerson(lovely);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a scoping issue:

```
var callPerson = function(person /* argument needs to be here */){
    console.log("Hey " + person.firstName + " " + person.lastName);
}
```

So `person` is the function, not the object `lovely`.

---

Minor code style remark: classes are typically capitalized, exactly to avoid this kind of confustion. Use `function Person () {/**/}` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It is not being logged because, in `callPerson`, the variable `person` refers to the function (constructor) `person`, since this name is not overridden in the scope of the function. This means you are not referring to some specific instance, but the class. Passing one instance as parameter doesn't change this since the function does not expect it; in effect, the passed parameter is not used in any means.

Think of this as attempting to log a class property, not one instance's.

Changing `callPerson` in the following way should solve your issue. Note that now the fields accessed are from the parameter `p`.

```
var callPerson = function(p){
    console.log("Hey " + p.firstName + " " + p.lastName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is the argument lovely storing it should have an parameter to store and use

```
function person(last, first, birth, marriage) {
this.lastName = last;
this.firstName = first;
this.birthDate = birth;
this.married = marriage;
}

var lovely = new person("Doughnut", "Glazed", "7-8-1990", true);

var callPerson = function(obj){
console.log("Hey " + obj.firstName + " " + obj.lastName);
}

callPerson(lovely);
```